# Your app uses 6 interfaces that are not part of the SDK

Tags: java, android, firebase-test-lab

I have the following warning at Firebase Test Lab:

```
Your app uses 6 interfaces that are not part of the SDK and are not supported by Android P and later.
Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z
Landroid /os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V
Landroid /os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V
Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V
Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I
Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V
```

I would like to know how could I solve that and what is causing the error Maybe some dependency is using those methods?